# dpkg-shlibdeps - how to use it for entire directory

Tags: debian, dpkg

My binary debian package is composed of many (~20+) executables. I am using dpkg-shlibdeps -O for individual executables in line with this [easy-to-follow guide](https://www.internalpointers.com/post/build-binary-deb-package-practical-guide), which gives me the Depends list I can then paste into my control file.

Is there a way to make this command search all the files in a directory so I can calculate all dependencies in a one-liner?
I tried `dpkg-shlibdeps -O dir_1/dir_2/*`, but this errors bc there is another directory inside dir_2. (Not to mention there is a warning:  binaries to analyze should already be installed in their package's directory).

TLDR: I would like to find the dependencies for the many executables in my binary debian package, so I can place them in my control file

Answer (score 0):

I recommend building using a source package rather than trying to build a binary package directly; that way, `shlibdeps` is taken care of for you (along with many other steps in the package build).

See [Vincent Bernat’s Pragmatic Debian packaging](https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2019-pragmatic-debian-packaging) for a simple approach to source-based packaging for Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: I found the binary tutorial linked in my OP the easiest way to get a debian package compiled and running, and source-based full of extraneous details, but I can check out that tutorial.